# Traefik on Swarm Mode in the same host

Tags: reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, traefik

I'm using Traefik as my reverse proxy and it's working perfectly, but I have some concerns about traefik on Swarm mode, because the reverse proxy is in the same host of swarm manager (according to the documentation https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm-mode/).

Please, could you highlight some problems I can face doing that when I go to Production? Is it really bad having the reverse proxy and swarm manager in the same host? What are the alternatives I have?

Best regards,
M